# Generate unique number when registering a new user

Tags: users, id

I know there are userID, username in the database, but I want a formatted and unique number for physical world use. For example: "2014xxxx" 201414:year,xxxx:generate randomly when registering a user.

Is it possible and if possible, what is the simplest way and fastest way to do so?

Comment: Why do you want that and how do you plan to use this unique number?

Answer (score 1):

This way would work ... the [user_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) action is fired when the user is stored in the data base. You can add meta data to a user with [add_metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/).

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    add_metadata( $user_id, 'unique_number', date( 'Y' ).str_pad( $user_id, 4 ) );

}
```

Comment: Use `add_user_meta` instead of `add_metadata`. Also I believe `unique` key should be set to true in this case.

Comment: @skibmoon, eh ... yes. Sorry :)

Comment: Should i paste this code to my function.php ?

Comment: If you don't want to wrap it in a Plugin, you need to paste that code to your functions.php. But please consider @sakibmoon's comment.

Comment: I just added add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'unique_number', date( 'Y' ).str_pad( $user_id, 4 ) );

}

Comment: but nothing happen in database. user id is incremented like 4 then 5 then 6.. like that.. I want it g2a1june then g2a2june  then g2a3june  like that..

Comment: nothing happen in database...any update??

Comment: nothing happen in database...any update?? –

Comment: Did you look in `wp_usermeta`? You shouldn't need to look in the database anyway. You can access the information with `get_user_meta` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve absolute unique userid in real world use case by using following code.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    $unique_id = date("Ymd").(int)microtime(true);
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'unique_number', $unique_id );
}
```

here I'm using `microtime()` to get the millisecond past from midnight. It will be always unique for everyday. To make sure it stays unique I have added YearMonthDate prefix. So unique id will look like this: `202006281593358887` we can part it like `2020` `06` `28` `1593358887`